# Sequelize belongsToMany: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasBrand' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, associations, sequelize.js

I have *User* and *Brand* models.

A user can have **many** brands.

A brand can belong **many** users.

I defined another model for many-to-many associations. It named *UserBrand*.

```
    // user.js
    const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        hasBrand: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            defaultValue: false,
        },
    })

    User.associate = models=> {
        User.belongsToMany(models.Brand, {
            through: models.UserBrand,
            foreignKey: 'user',
        })
    }

    // brand.js
    Brand.belongsToMany(models.User, {
        through: models.UserBrand,
        foreignKey: 'brand',
    })

    // userBrand.js
    const UserBrand = sequelize.define('UserBrand', {
        status: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            defaultValue: '',
        },
    })

    UserBrand.associate = models=> {
        UserBrand.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'user', targetKey: 'id' })
        UserBrand.belongsTo(models.Brand, { foreignKey: 'brand', targetKey: 'id' })
    }
```

When I run my application, it shows `TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasBrand' of undefined`. I can not find any relation between *hasBrand* and *association*, but remove *hasBrand* it works

How can I fix it in case I still want to keep *hasBrand* field?

Comment: *hasBrand* is only a field of User model

Comment: I added full code snippet :(

Comment: Add running code, messy :? With Run snippet button

Comment: Yep, a little bit messy and I was thinking that the root cause here is model definition.